# mysql error on cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I just saw this error today. I have been using mysql on the cloud for a while. Please tell me why I am getting this access error now.

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user 'uumI5f9ZOSxVz'@'172.30.49.187' for table 'person'

Comment: Stupid mistake in my JPA class.  I forgot to remove 'catolog="database".   Since in the cloud there is already one this would create an access error.

Answer (score 3):

As the original user posted in a comment,

> I forgot to remove 'catolog="database". Since in the cloud there is already one this would create an access error. – Matt Srum May 29 at 18:14